# SWT Table without selection

Tags: java, swt, selection

I am looking for a solution which disables the selection highlighting completely. I've got the following approach:

```
table.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
{
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event)
    {
        event.detail = SWT.NONE;
        event.type = SWT.None;
        event.doit = false;
        try
        {
            table.setRedraw(false);
            table.deselectAll();
        }
        finally
        {
            table.setRedraw(true);
        }
    }
});
```

But it's somehow only half-solved my requirement. The background highlighting is gone indeed, but the rectangle around the selection still appears:

[image]

And if you look at the rectangle more precisely, you will see that it looks ugly especially around the checkbox. This is in fact the main reason why I want do disable the selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force the focus on another `Widget` that's not your `Table`. By doing that, you'll loose the dotted line (which represents the focus).

Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, true));

    final Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Focus catcher");

    final Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);

    for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
        new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE).setText("Col " + col);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);

        for (int col = 0; col < table.getColumnCount(); col++)
            item.setText(col, "Cell " + i + " " + col);
    }

    for (int col = 0; col < table.getColumnCount(); col++)
        table.getColumn(col).pack();

    table.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            table.deselectAll();

            button.setFocus();
            button.forceFocus();
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I created an invisible button `invisibleButton = new Button(table, SWT.NONE); invisibleButton.setVisible(false);` and redirect the focus to it if needed `invisibleButton.setFocus(); invisibleButton.forceFocus();` (it's slightly more complicated than your example because one of the columns is editable). But why does the style option SWT.NO_FOCUS not do what it is supposed to do?

Comment: @DanyloEsterman A lot of the style bits are just hints. The OS might respect them or it might now.

Comment: I've got another small question. Do I really need to reset all fields of the `event` object?

Comment: @DanyloEsterman No, `event.doit = false` should be sufficient.

Comment: @DanyloEsterman Just tested, you don't even need `event.doit = false`, cause it's not actually preventing the event anyway.

Comment: Yep I wondered already if it makes a difference. The `SelectionEvent` is fired after the selection was made, isn't it?

Comment: @DanyloEsterman You can even use [this](http://vyshemirsky.blogspot.co.uk/2007/07/eclipse-swt-disabling-selection-event.html) rather than deselecting all elements manually. Looks like a cleaner solution. You'll still need to loose the focus though.

Comment: Switched to the suggested solution which works for the selection as well. Using the `EraseItem` event appears mystical to me though. And the following expression seems not quite clear for me too: `event.detail &= ~SWT.SELECTED;` I'd rather use `event.detail ^= SWT.SELECTED;` if I wanted to keep the other event details and if there's any.

Comment: @DanyloEsterman Looking at the code of `Shell` for example you'll see `&= ~SOMETHING` all the time. XOR doesn't seem right here.

Comment: If we have 2 details in an event: `SWT.SELECTED` which is 2 and some other which is let's say 8, then `event.detail` would look like this `1010`. I want to set `SWT.SELECTED` to `0`, right? `1010` XOR `0010` = `1000`. Using an AND with the negative of `SWT.SELECTED` will clear the whole thing: `1010` AND `0000` = `0000`. Am I overseeing something?

Comment: @DanyloEsterman You just want to remove `SWT.SELECTED` from the `event.detail`, if it's position is `1` the `&= ~` will set it to `0`, if it's `0`, it'll still be 0.

Comment: Since we check if `SWT.SELECTED` is set, XOR will set it to zero as well. But with the big difference: it won't set the other flags to zero.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57917/discussion-between-baz-and-danylo-esterman).